# How to return a collection of cross-referenced data from a function?

Tags: rust, reference, traits, borrow-checker

In the following code I have a model, representing the state of a physical system. Within the model I would like to have two balls connected by a spring.

```
fn model(_app: &App) -> Model {
    let mut ball1 = Ball::new(-250.0, 0.0, 50.0);
    let mut ball2 = Ball::new(250.0, 0.0, 50.0);
    let spring = Spring::new(&mut ball1, &mut ball2, 0.1);
    Model {
        objs: vec![
            Box::new(ball1),
            Box::new(ball2),
            Box::new(spring),
        ],
    }
}
```

The definition for my `Model` is as follows:

```
struct Model {
    objs: Vec<Box<dyn PhysicsObject>>,
}
```

And the definitions for `Spring` and `Spring::new()` are:

```
pub struct Spring<'a> {
    pub target_length: f32,
    pub a: &'a mut Ball,
    pub b: &'a mut Ball,
}
impl<'a> Spring<'a> {
    pub fn new(b1: &'a mut Ball, b2: &'a mut Ball, k: f32) -> Spring<'a>{
        Spring{
            target_length: (b1.position - b2.position).mag(),
            a: b1,
            b: b2,
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently getting the following compiler error, due to (I belive) passing the balls references to the `Spring`, and then trying to return them (in a box) from the function.

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `ball1` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:21:22
   |
18 |     let spring = Spring::new(&mut ball1, &mut ball2, 0.1);
   |                              ---------- borrow of `ball1` occurs here
...
21 |             Box::new(ball1),
   |                      ^^^^^ move out of `ball1` occurs here
22 |             Box::new(ball2),
23 |             Box::new(spring),
   |             ---------------- cast requires that `ball1` is borrowed for `'static`
```

(I also get an identical error for `ball2`)
How would I restructure my code in order to get the desired behavior? A spring needs to be able to update the balls it's attached to, and multiple spring should be able to be attached to one ball, which is currently impossible. I have a feeling this might be what an `Rc` is for, but I'm really no sure where to start with that. Thanks.

P.S. I am using `nannou`, a graphics library, which is where the `App` type comes from. However I do not think that's relevant to my issue.

P.P.S. Here's the definition for the `PhysicsObject` and the type `Ball` in case either are relevant.

```
pub trait PhysicsObject {
    fn update(&mut self, dt: f32);

    fn show(&self, draw: &Draw);
}

pub struct Ball {
    pub color: Rgb<f64>,
    pub radius: f32,
    pub position: V2,
    pub velocity: V2,
    pub acceleration: V2,
    pub mass: f32,
}
impl Ball {
    pub fn new(x: f32, y: f32, r: f32) -> Ball {
        Ball {
            color: rgb(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            radius: r,
            position: v2(x, y),
            velocity: V2::zero(),
            acceleration: V2::zero(),
            mass: 1.0,
        }
    }
    pub fn applyForce(&mut self, f: V2) { //The function that `Spring` calls
        self.acceleration += f / self.mass;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide definitions for `Ball`, `Spring`, and all other types here as part of a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I added the error message as well as the definitions for `Ball` and `PhyicsObject`. The definition for `Spring` is already included. @cafce25 @PitaJ

Comment: You can't hold mutable references to the balls while also moving the balls into boxes in the vec.

Comment: I understand that, I guess my actual question was worded rather unclearly. I was wondering how I could rework my code in order to get the desired behavior, or whether theirs something I'm fundamentally misunderstanding. I want to be able to have a list of objects, while also having those objects within the list contain references to each other. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am currently getting the following compiler error, due to (I belive) passing the balls references to the Spring, and then trying to return them (in a box) from the function.

That's exactly right. You'll have to come up with another way to refer to the `Balls` in the model.

One way to go about this would be to use indices into the `Model.objs` vector in the `Springs` but that way you can only access methods by the `PyhsicalObject` trait.

Another is to share ownership with `Rc`:

```rust
fn model(_app: &App) -> Model {
    let ball1 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Ball::new(-250.0, 0.0, 50.0)));
    let ball2 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Ball::new(250.0, 0.0, 50.0)));
    let spring = Spring::new(ball1.clone(), ball2.clone(), 0.1);
    Model {
        objs: vec![
            Box::new(ball1),
            Box::new(ball2),
            Box::new(spring),
        ],
    }
}
```

```rust
impl<'a> Spring<'a> {
    pub fn new(b1: Rc<RefCell<Ball>>, b2: Rc<RefCell<Ball>>, _k: f32) -> Spring<'a>{
        Spring{
            target_length: (b1.borrow().position - b2.borrow().position).mag(),
            a: b1,
            b: b2,
        }
    }
    fn update(&self) {
        let f = v2(1.0, 0.0); // whatever force you need
        self.a.borrow_mut().applyForce(f);
        self.b.borrow_mut().applyForce(-f);
    }
}
```

```rust
impl PyhsicalObject for Rc<RefCell<Ball>> {
    //…
}
```

and adjust `Ball` to `Rc<RefCell<Ball>>` in most other places.

But using a lot of `Rc<RefCell<T>>` typically means you need to rethink your data model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm still having issues but it was definitely helpful. I am curious about your last statement though. If this question is too vague or you don't have enough info of my program that's fine, but is there any sort of data model where I wouldn't need `Rc`? It seems like it's necessary since I require multiple different springs to have simultaneous mutable references to the same ball.

Comment: In your case the `model` could handle everything that needs mutability and the `Springs` could only hold on to 'ball_id's If that's better or worse than `RefCell` I can't say.